# Find remainder when P(x) is divided by x²-3x+2

Tags: polynomials

I'm a bit confused on the working to this question. A friend of mine gave me a solution but I dont quite understand why is the working like that.

> When $P(x)$ is divided by $(x-1)$ and $(x-2)$, the remainder is $5$ and $3$ respectively. Find the remainder when it is divided by $(x^2-3x+2)$

And this is the working given to me:

$$\begin{align}
P(x) &= Q(x)P(x) + R(x)\\
&= Q(x)P(x) + (ax+b)
\end{align}$$

Remainder Theorem: $P(c) = r$

$$P(c) = r = ax + b$$
$$P(1) = 5 = a(1) + b\tag1$$
$$P(2) = 3 = a(2) + b\tag2$$

$$a = -2 \qquad b = 7\\[5pt]
-2x + 7$$

Why is that when we do simultaneous equation of both these roots and remainder, we get the root function of $x^2-3x+2$ ? I know that $(x-1)(x-2) = (x^2-3x+2)$, but I just don't understand the reason of that working.

Answer (score 2):

It is the remainder theorem that if you divide $P(x)$ by the degree two $x^2-3x+2$, the remainder will be a degree one polynomial. Hence,

$$P(x) = (x^2-3x+2)Q(x) + (ax+b)$$

Now, this is an identity for all values of $x$. Thus if in particular you plug in $x=1$ on both sides, you'll get an equation. But notice that $x=1 \implies x^2-3x+2=0$, so you're left with $a(1)+b$ on the RHS.

Similar argument applies to other values and divisions.

Comment: I see.. so that is how it works.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand the work you showed without any formatting (not sure where one statement begins and the next ends). I'll write out how I approached the problem.

We know that for some polynomials $f, g$

$$P(x) = (x-1)f(x) + 5$$
$$P(x) = (x-2)g(x) + 3$$

Multiplying $(x-2)$ to the top equation and $(x-1)$ to the bottom gives

$$(x-2)P(x) = (x-1)(x-2)f(x) + 5(x-2)$$
$$(x-1)P(x) = (x-1)(x-2)g(x) + 3(x-1)$$

Subtracting the $2$ equations gives

$$-P(x) = (x-1)(x-2)(f(x) - g(x)) + 2x-7$$

Letting $h(x) = g(x) - f(x)$ be a polynomial and simplifying,

$$P(x) = (x^2 - 3x + 2)h(x) + (-2x+7)$$

Then the remainder is $-2x+7$, which is different from the answer you give.

Comment: See @Behnam 's answer. It's quite a bit slicker.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally wrote the wrong answer, I've edited it. Thanks for this working